# sql query to combine 2 field

Tags: sql, field

I have a query which retrieve from few tables but 2 tables having same field value,

Query is

```
SELECT A.NUM_RIF, B.NDG, D.NDG FROM ICGR1100 A 
LEFT JOIN (ICGR1105 E INNER JOIN ICGR1101 D ON E.C_IST=D.C_IST AND E.DT_DOM_NDG=D.DT_DOM_NDG AND E.N_DOM=D.N_DOM) ON A.C_IST=E.C_IST AND A.NUM_RIF=E.NUM_RIF 
LEFT JOIN ICGR1103 B ON A.C_IST=B.C_IST AND A.NUM_RIF=B.NUM_RIF
```

Result is:

```
NUM_RIF           NDG               NDG              
 ----------------  ----------------  ---------------- 
0000000000000981  (null)            0000000000002490 
0000000000000985  (null)            0000000000002490 
0000009000004523  0000000000001775  (null)                   
0000009000004521  0000000000001775  (null)           
0000009000004218  0000000000001775  (null)           
0000000000000980  (null)            (null)           
0000009000004914                    0000000000002490 
0000009000004917                    
0000009000004923                    0000000000002490
```

So my expectation result is as below:

```
NUM_RIF           NDG                           
 ----------------  ---------------- 
0000000000000981  0000000000002490 
0000000000000985  0000000000002490 
0000009000004523  0000000000001775                 
0000009000004521  0000000000001775           
0000009000004218  0000000000001775          
0000000000000980  (null)                   
0000009000004914  0000000000002490 
0000009000004914  
0000009000004923  0000000000002490
```

the case is both field might have empty value, or null, or either one will be empty/null, but so far don't have value in both field, which mean only one field have value

Comment: Can both columns have a value on the same row?

Comment: Is it always true that at most one of the NDGs has a value?

Comment: What is the value of `NDG` where `NUM_RIF = 0000009000004914`? In your example, the column is whitespace whereas above you have typed `(null)`. e.g. is it a zero = length string? Also, do you have a particular SQL product in mind? (with the name Apache I'd guess mySQL ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most dbmss have a NVL like function:

```
NVL(B.NDG, D.NDG) as NDG
```

Will return B.NDG if not null otherwise D.NDG

NVL is for Oracle but there's probably an equivalent for your dbms

Comment: or `Coalesce(B.NDG, D.NDG) as NDG` also will work fine. but, this logic has an issue, it only takes `d.ndg` if the 1st paramater `b.ndg` is null. So choose your 1st parameter wisely

Comment: @NaveenBabu, yes I think it is SQL server's equivalent for NVL

Comment: @NaveenBabu: `COALESCE()` is the Standard SQL equivalent which is indeed implemented by SQL Server. SQL Server also has a proprietary `ISNULL()` function with slightly different semantics.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried

```
SELECT A.NUM_RIF, COALESCE(B.NDG, D.NDG) FROM ICGR1100 A
...
```